# Trim all characters before a certain substring (php)

Tags: php, string, substring

I have this string:

> `"(data I don't care about) (invariable substring) (data I care about)"`

How do I trim all the data I don't care about, knowing the invariable substring?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP remove all characters before specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802821/php-remove-all-characters-before-specific-string)

Answer (score 2):

This should suffice:

```
substr($string, (int)strpos("invariablestring", $string));
```

But will leave the invariablestring untouched. If you want to remove that string, just add it's length to the value strpos() returned.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the offset and only take the substring from that offset on:

```
if (($pos = strpos($str, $substr)) !== false) {
    $str = substr($str, $pos);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest I've found is:

```
list(, $data_i_care_about) = explode('(invariable substring)', $all_the_data, 2)
```