# PHP remove all characters before specific string

Tags: php, string

I need to remove all characters from any string before the occurrence of this inside the string:

```
"www/audio"
```

Not sure how I can do this.

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->afterFirst('www/audio')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L435) or [`s($str)->afterLast('www/audio')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L445) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Comment: For the single character, check: [How to remove everything before the first specific character in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5329866/55075)

Answer (score 201, accepted):

You can use [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) to do this.

```
echo strstr($str, 'www/audio');
```

Comment: Quick note: you can use `strstr()` to return the part of the string that comes **before** its argument too by calling `echo strstr($str, 'www/audio', true);`

Answer (score 24):

Considering

```
$string="We have www/audio path where the audio files are stored";  //Considering the string like this
```

Either you can use

```
strstr($string, 'www/audio');
```

Or

```
$expStr=explode("www/audio",$string);
$resultString="www/audio".$expStr[1];
```

Comment: string functions are generally faster than array functions

Comment: The explode is in fact a better answer, as the question was about _removing_ the text before the string.

Comment: explode could cause problems if you had multiple occurrences of the same string you were trying to remove - e.g. "we have www/audio path where the www/audio files are stored" would result in "path where the" if you wanted to use explode you could do something like

foreach ( $expStr as $key => $value )
  echo ( $key == 0 ? '' :  'www/audio'.$value ) ;  

or 

foreach ( $expStr as $key => $value )
  echo ( $key == 0 ? '' :  ( $key == 1 ? '' : 'www/audio' ).$value ) ;  

if you wanted to omit the initial www/audio.

Answer (score 2):

I use this functions

```
function strright($str, $separator) {
    if (intval($separator)) {
        return substr($str, -$separator);
    } elseif ($separator === 0) {
        return $str;
    } else {
        $strpos = strpos($str, $separator);

        if ($strpos === false) {
            return $str;
        } else {
            return substr($str, -$strpos + 1);
        }
    }
}

function strleft($str, $separator) {
    if (intval($separator)) {
        return substr($str, 0, $separator);
    } elseif ($separator === 0) {
        return $str;
    } else {
        $strpos = strpos($str, $separator);

        if ($strpos === false) {
            return $str;
        } else {
            return substr($str, 0, $strpos);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well for multiple occurrences of the same string. Thanks!

Comment: for right remove - from the substr to get complete string after the first occurance of the seperator

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to accomplish this goal.

You could also use a [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to pattern match only what you want. Your mileage may vary on which of these approaches makes more sense.